# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. $S=\{g\in G\mid ghg^{-1}\in H\}$. Is $S= N_{G(H)}$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

$S=\{g\in G\mid ghg^{-1}\in H,\forall h\in H\}$.

I know that $N_G(H)\subset S$. But I can't seem to find any counterexamples for the other inclusion. Any ideas?

Comment: It is the very definition of the normaliser of a subgroup.

Comment: Note that if $gHg^{-1} \subset H$, then actually $gHg^{-1} = H$.